# How to fill progress bar according to calculated data

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I have a progress bar and want to fill according to percentage of consumption of items. And here i have total number of items and consumed items.

**Here is my code**

```
<div>
                    <p class="pull-left">Contacts Added</p>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <?php echo $data['customer'] . '/' . $plan_details[0]['contact']; ?>
                    </p>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                            <div class="progress-bar bg-green" id="contactsAdded" role="progressbar"
                                 data-transitiongoal=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in the above code `$data['customer']` have contains total permitted customers for signup and `$plan_details[0]['contact']` have contains total already registered customers.

Now i want to fill progress bar according calculation of these two values. So kindly suggest me about this logic to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can calculate parentage of consumed items for filling your progress bar.

Something like this:

```
var getContacts = '<?php echo $plan_details[0]['contact']; ?>';
var AddedContacts = '<?php echo $data['customer']; ?>';
var restContacts = AddedContacts*100/getContacts;
$("#contactsAdded").css({ "width": + restContacts + "%" });
$("#contactsAdded").attr('data-transitiongoal', restContacts);
```

Comment: can you guide me where can i place your code within my code?

Comment: just below of your code after jquery initialization.